# Curl Location.reload(true) Result

Tags: php, curl

### When I try to get markafoni.com's html data with CURL, it returns;

```
<script>
document.cookie = 'NSId=2;expires=Sun, 17-Jan-2038 01:00:00 GMT';
location.reload(true);
</script><noscript>%90'a varan indirim Markafoni'de</noscript>
```

---

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.markafoni.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.markafoni.com/');
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @lonesomeday The problem is that, when I use this php code; it returns no data, it just returns javascript code that contains location reload, so it always refreshing. If you try my PHP code once, you'll understand what the problem is

Comment: I imagine the site will work once the cookie has been set. Try setting the `NSId=2` cookie.

Comment: @lonesomeday could you show me how to set cookie as NSId=2 ?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'NSId=2');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the server's technique for setting cookies, which is rather idiosyncratic. It may in fact be intended to prevent screen-scraping like you're doing, but there may be other reasons.

The server clearly has two different responses.

1. If there is no `NSId` cookie set, send some Javascript to set one and send nothing else.
2. If there is an `NSId` cookie set, send the page content.

cURL obviously can receive and set cookies from the server, as you do with the following code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

This, however, presumes that the server is setting cookies in the normal way, i.e. using the `Cookie` HTTP header. Since it's doing it with Javascript (highly idiosyncratic!) cURL doesn't understand it.

You'll have to set the cookie yourself using the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'NSId=2');
```

The `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option sets the cookie string to be sent by cURL.